# ATtiny measuring voltage for battery charger

Tags: batteries, adc, charger, attiny

Would it be possible to use adc with the reference voltage at ground, to determine the voltage of say a battery? I was thinking of creating a battery charger with the attiny for automatic cutoff and such. Or would there be an easier way of achieving this? I would assume some analog circuits would work, but I'm not sure which route is best. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ATTINY A/D converter. But you do not want the reference voltage near GND. The reference voltage determines the full scale voltage to which the A/D converter will convert. So you will want to have the VREF set to a voltage that is at or above the maximum battery voltage you will be wanting to read.

Comment: To clarify, this applies to the ATTINY, but not all A/D converters, integrated or otherwise. For example, some TI differential A/D's have Vref as midscale .

Comment: So you mean by midscale that the Vref is 512 for a 10bit a/d? Just want to understand better.